# Plotting standard error

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to create a chart with the std error but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want it to. I want to get rid of the line between every entry. This is what I have right now:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis} \addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit]
    coordinates { (0,0) +- (0.5,2) (0.5,1) +- (0.4,0.2) (1,2) (2,5) +- (1,0.1) };
\end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

And I also wonder how you can read data form a .txt file and put it into the plot as well with x and y labels.

```
Data.txt:<br>

X Y Y_error
124 3.385995 0.866002
112 3.133745 0.937226
99 2.906316 0.895013
87 2.586054 0.835342
74 2.346789 0.792954
61 2.283117 0.699818
49 2.012212 0.909995
37 1.919941 1.366541
24 1.809623 1.691634
11 5.603446 13.825383
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is too long for a comment and I don't want to mess with @Jesse's answer - which obviously is the base for this - my take on what you're trying to achieve is:

*Update*: reversing the x axis is easily achieved with `x dir=reverse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
124 3.385995 0.866002
112 3.133745 0.937226
99 2.906316 0.895013
87 2.586054 0.835342
74 2.346789 0.792954
61 2.283117 0.699818
49 2.012212 0.909995
37 1.919941 1.366541
24 1.809623 1.691634
11 5.603446 13.825383
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[x dir=reverse]
\addplot+[only marks, mark=o,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]
 coordinates { 
(0,0)    +- (0.5,2) 
(0.5,1) +- (0.4,0.2) 
(1,2) 
(2,5)    +- (1,0.1) };
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x dir=reverse]
\addplot [color=blue, only marks,mark=o,]
 plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
 table[row sep=crcr, y error index=2]{\jobname.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

As @Jesse noted, the magic lies in `only marks,mark=o` for suppressing the line, while `plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]` sets what error bars are to be shown and `y error index=2` specifies their position in the data table.

[image: output]

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** based on @greyshade's comment, I mis-interpreted the data. So this is the data from external file.

```
 x      y       ey
124 3.385995 0.866002
112 3.133745 0.937226
99  2.906316 0.895013
87  2.586054 0.835342
74  2.346789 0.792954
61  2.283117 0.699818
49  2.012212 0.909995
37  1.919941 1.366541
24  1.809623 1.691634
11  5.603446 13.825383
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot [color=blue, only marks, mark=o,]
 plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
 table[x =x, y =y, y error =ey]{dataerror.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Would this be what you tried to obtain! The key is use `only marks` and select `mark=o`. Further, you data file for x y is unclear, I assume the following set and put them into an external file call `dataerror.dat` so that they can be read into, as shown in the third method.

```
x  y  ex      ey
12 4 3.385995 0.866002
11 2 3.133745 0.937226
9 9 2.906316 0.895013
8 7 2.586054 0.835342
7 4 2.346789 0.792954
6 1 2.283117 0.699818
4 9 2.012212 0.909995
3 7 1.919941 1.366541
2 4 1.809623 1.691634
1 1 5.603446 13.825383
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot+[only marks, mark=o,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]
 coordinates { 
(0,0)    +- (0.5,2) 
(0.5,1) +- (0.4,0.2) 
(1,2) 
(2,5)    +- (1,0.1) };
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

% data from internal setting

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot [color=blue, only marks,mark=o,]
 plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
 table[row sep=crcr, x index=0, y index=1, x error index=2, y error index=3,]{
12 4 3.385995 0.866002\\
11 2 3.133745 0.937226\\
9 9 2.906316 0.895013\\
8 7 2.586054 0.835342\\
7 4 2.346789 0.792954\\
6 1 2.283117 0.699818\\
4 9 2.012212 0.909995\\
3 7 1.919941 1.366541\\
2 4 1.809623 1.691634\\
1 1 5.603446 13.825383\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

% data from external setting

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot [color=blue, only marks, mark=o,]
 plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
 table[x =x, y =y, x error=ex, y error =ey,]{dataerror.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: good answer, but I don't follow your comment on his data file at all! He's got three colums: `x value`, `y value` and `y error` - which is exactly what your example uses; i.e. if you compare your plot and the numbers, the fourth column (i.e. what used to be his third) if completely unused!

Comment: @greyshade -- thanks for the comment. I observed that too, working on that.

Comment: just use his data in stead of what you made of it and I guess you'd have the answer he wants.

Comment: now again, why would you edit his data and not just take it for what it is? you're not showing the new `x error` column you just invented.. (and he obviously does not intend to have `x error` bars shown..)

Comment: You are right, my interpretation of OP's data was wrong.

Comment: This is almost what I was looking for but I will mark this as the answer. What I wanted was to have the highest value(124) as xmin and the lowest value(11) as xmax. Thanks @greyshade for the correction.

Comment: @ChrisG inverting the x axis is easily achieved with `x dir=reverse`, also see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43159/reversing-direction-of-x-axis-in-pgfplots). I've edited my answer below accordingly.