# Reverse axis in TikZ \datavisualization

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

Sorry if this doesn't seem well-researched, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Is there a way to reverse an axis in a TikZ `\datavisualization`? Concretely, I want to reverse the `y` axis in a cartesian system, so that positive points down.

---

**Clarification:** I didn't express myself correctly. Basically I only want to get a `y` axis in which positive is down and negative is
up. But that's not simply putting the `$y$` label at the bottom; I
actually want positive to be down and the arrow to point down. The
"aiming for" image is confusing because there are no tick marks. But
if I added them, the y axis would show 1 (and not -1). Of course, then
the whole graph would appear on the opposite side. But I could easily
change the `csv` files to reverse all of the y coordinates. In fact, the
only reason I put negative y coordinates in the csv files was
precisely because I didn't know how to "properly" flip the axis, but
the original data is all positive (both in `x` and `y`). Sorry for the confusion.
[@whatisit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/78866/whatisit) gave the solution straight away, which was `yscale=-1`.
Now the only problem is getting the correct anchoring of tick
marks/labels. Again, sorry for the confusion.

---

From what I've gathered from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43159/reversing-direction-of-x-axis-in-pgfplots) question, when manually specifying an `axis` you can use the key `y dir=reverse`. But I haven't found any equivalent way using the `\datavisualization` library. I'm using the `school book axes` system.

Here's what I've tried:

```
\datavisualization [school book axes,
                    y dir=reverse]
```

```
\datavisualization [school book axes,
                    all axes={y dir=reverse}]
```

```
\datavisualization [school book axes,
                    y axis=reverse]
```

```
\datavisualization [school book axes,
                    y={dir=reverse}]
```

## MWE (updated)

This is what I'm working on. I've stripped down the preamble to a minimum.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{1.csv}
0, 0
0.100000, 0.102985
0.200000, 0.284078
0.300000, 0.431294
0.800000, 0.886640
0.900000, 0.946767
1.000000, 1.000000
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{2.csv}
0, 0
0.104298, 0.280000
0.213643, 0.440000
0.300496, 0.540000
0.709127, 0.860000
0.820097, 0.920000
0.904455, 0.960000
1.000000, 1.000000
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{3.csv}
0, 0
0.105170, 0.292368
0.205373, 0.440170
0.325606, 0.575855
0.435812, 0.676699
0.502248, 0.729587
0.663074, 0.838455
0.760352, 0.893359
0.871594, 0.947572
1.000000, 1.000000
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
        \datavisualization data group {methods} = {
            data [set=m1, read from file={1.csv}]
            data [set=m2, read from file={2.csv}]
            data [set=m3, read from file={3.csv}]
        };

        \datavisualization [school book axes,
                            visualize as scatter/.list={m1,m3,m2},
                            all axes={unit length=8cm},
                            x axis={label=$x$},
                            y axis={label=$y$},
                            yscale=-1,
                            style sheet={vary hue},
                            style sheet={cross marks},
                            data/headline={x,y}]

            data group {methods};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The complete CSV files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1E13zEN5eNDbcLl6wHaz6RTIHDPb-vSb3?usp=sharing).

### Current output (updated)

Note: as [@whatisit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/78866/whatisit) suggested, I'm using `yscale=-`. The problem now is how to change the label/tick anchoring.

[image: current output (updated)]

## What I'm aiming for

Something like this:

[image: desired ouput indication]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, scale=6]
        \coordinate (X) at (1.3, 0);
        \coordinate (Y) at (0, -1.1);
        \draw[black!30, very thin] (X) grid (Y);
        \draw[black!5, very thin, step=0.2] (X) grid (Y);

        \draw[->, very thick]  (0, 0) -- node[very near end, anchor=south west] {\Large$x$} (X);
        \draw[->, very thick]  (0, 0) -- node[very near end, anchor=north east] {\Large$y$} (Y);

        \draw[blue, loosely dotted, very thick] plot file {1.data};
        \draw[purple, loosely dotted, ultra thick] plot file {2.data};
        \draw[red, loosely dotted, very thick] plot file {3.data};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here `1.data`, `2.data` and `3.data` are exactly like the CSV files but separated by spaces instead of commas.

Comment: Can you use `\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]`?  This will flip *all* y coordinates to the opposite sign.  (You can also use this option in `\datavisualization` instead)

Comment: @whatisit Yes, the problem then is that the label positioning gets all messed up, and I can't figure out the syntax of `anchor`

Comment: Generally, your posts are interesting but require a lot of effort by those who are considering to answer them. I dare to predict that, once you provide minimal working examples, i.e. documents that start with `\documentclass`, end with `\end{document}`, can be compiled and illustrate the point you will get very quickly answers and also upvotes to your question.

Comment: Still the files `1.csv`, `2.csv` and `3.csv` are still missing. You can include them using `filecontents`, which makes it more convenient for others. And even if I add them, the document cannot be compiled. Further, why are you loading `pgfplots` here? You do not seem to use it. Of course, if you use it, you can easily reverse axes.

Comment: @marmot I updated the filenames accordingly; `1.csv`, `2.csv` and `3.csv` were placeholder names. I tried compiling and it works fine for me. I'm hesitant to put `filecontents` because the files are large.

Comment: If the entire files aren't needed to replicate the problem, then there is no need for the entire files. Two lines of one file is likely enough for demonstration.

Comment: Looking at your updates, I'm now a bit confused about what you're looking for.  Originally, you wanted the y-axis flipped, but your "aiming for" image looks nearly identical to the first image.  Do you simply want "y" to be at the bottom of the axis, instead of the top?

Comment: @whatisit Yes, sorry about that, I should have been clearer. I didn't express myself correctly. Basically I only want to get a `y` axis in which positive is down and negative is up. But that's not simply putting the `$y$` label at the bottom; I actually want positive to be down and the arrow to point down. The "aiming for" image is confusing because there are no tick marks. But if I added them, the `y` axis would show 1 (and *not* -1). Of course, then the whole graph would appear on the opposite side. But I could easily change the `csv` files to reverse all of the `y` coordinates.

Comment: @whatisit In fact, the only reason I put negative `y` coordinates in the `csv` files was precisely because I didn't know how to "properly" flip the axis, but the original data is all positive (both in `x` and `y`). Nevertheless, your contribution is still very helpful. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Anakhand ok, so it's basically the same thing, except the y data is flipped.  Plus, some visual changes.  I will follow-up after taking a look again at it.

Comment: @Anakhand I've made a major edit to my answer.  It looks as close as I could to the desired image. Hope this what you were aiming for!

Comment: @whatisit Yes, it's perfect, thank you! It's great that you left your original contribution too, so people looking for that solution will find it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this was a little tricky, but I was able to figure it out with `data visualization`.  The approach scales the y-axis by -1 (as mentioned in my comment).  As you mentioned, however, this also flips the axis values and not only the data.

**Updated Version**

Based on the updated description/question, here is a version that looks the closest to the desired image.  Honestly, there are no tick labels in that version...so my previous answers are largely unnecessary (flip the scale and remove the ticks!).

The axes labels aren't positioned vary nicely by default, so I included a small shift for each, to look like your image.  Added a grid which appears in the image.  Color coded them...because too many X's from different data sets is confusing.  Finally, you'll notice that the x and y `min value` are set to `0.045`; this was because the grids *and* axes overlapped for some reason...this was just a tweak so that the intersect without any overlap (really, just a hack for appearance purposes).

Last note: I removed the negative sign from the filecontents.  So, what you are see is *positive* y values on the *negative* y-axis, as request from the original question.

```
% ---DOCUMENT CLASS---
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

% ---MISC. PACKAGES---
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% ---TIKZ---
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

% ---PLOTS---
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{1.csv}
0, 0
0.020000, 0.000347
0.040000, 0.009989
0.060000, 0.033917
0.080000, 0.066399
0.100000, 0.102985
0.120000, 0.140917
0.140000, 0.178608
0.160000, 0.215232
0.180000, 0.250425
0.200000, 0.284078
0.220000, 0.316210
0.240000, 0.346897
0.260000, 0.376240
0.280000, 0.404339
0.300000, 0.431294
0.320000, 0.457194
0.340000, 0.482119
0.780000, 0.873711
0.800000, 0.886640
0.820000, 0.899258
0.840000, 0.911571
0.860000, 0.923589
0.880000, 0.935319
0.900000, 0.946767
0.920000, 0.957940
0.940000, 0.968844
0.960000, 0.979485
0.980000, 0.989869
1.000000, 1.000000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{2.csv}
0, 0
0.002644, 0.020000
0.006417, 0.040000
0.011080, 0.060000
0.016513, 0.080000
0.022645, 0.100000
0.029425, 0.120000
0.036820, 0.140000
0.044804, 0.160000
0.053358, 0.180000
0.062468, 0.200000
0.072123, 0.220000
0.082316, 0.240000
0.093042, 0.260000
0.104298, 0.280000
0.116083, 0.300000
0.128398, 0.320000
0.141246, 0.340000
0.154629, 0.360000
0.168553, 0.380000
0.183024, 0.400000
0.198051, 0.420000
0.213643, 0.440000
0.229810, 0.460000
0.246564, 0.480000
0.263919, 0.500000
0.281891, 0.520000
0.300496, 0.540000
0.643284, 0.820000
0.675487, 0.840000
0.709127, 0.860000
0.744333, 0.880000
0.781261, 0.900000
0.820097, 0.920000
0.861068, 0.940000
0.904455, 0.960000
0.950612, 0.980000
1.000000, 1.000000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{3.csv}
0, 0
0.007957, 0.055479
0.010327, 0.065792
0.013265, 0.077471
0.016876, 0.090623
0.021278, 0.105355
0.026607, 0.121775
0.033015, 0.139989
0.040673, 0.160100
0.049771, 0.182208
0.060520, 0.206407
0.073158, 0.232783
0.087945, 0.261415
0.105170, 0.292368
0.125154, 0.325696
0.148248, 0.361432
0.174844, 0.399593
0.205373, 0.440170
0.280191, 0.528391
0.325606, 0.575855
0.377226, 0.625362
0.435812, 0.676699
0.502248, 0.729587
0.577578, 0.783662
0.663074, 0.838455
0.760352, 0.893359
0.871594, 0.947572
1.000000, 1.000000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[school book axes,
                            all axes={length=6cm},
                            x axis={min value=0.045,
                                    max value=1.0,
                                    label={[node style={xshift=-1em,yshift=1ex}]{$x$}},
                                    ticks=none,
                                    grid={minor={at={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1}}}
                                    },
                            y axis={min value=0.045,
                                    max value=1.0,
                                    label={[node style={xshift=-0.5em,yshift=0.5ex}]{$y$}},
                                    ticks=none,
                                    grid={minor={at={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1}}}
                                    },
                            yscale=-1,
                                visualize as scatter/.list={a,b,c},
                                style sheet=strong colors]%

            data[set=a, headline={x, y}, read from file={1.csv}]
            data[set=b, headline={x, y}, read from file={2.csv}]
            data[set=c, headline={x, y}, read from file={3.csv}]
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Updated axis shift yscale and colors and grid]

**Original approach:**

Perhaps this is not the most elegant approach, but you can forcibly "re-calculate" the y-value tick labels with:

```
\def\reverseyaxis#1{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1*-1}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}
```

And then update the `ticks` values within `\datavisualization` parameters:

```
tick typesetter/.code=\reverseyaxis{##1}
```

Here is a complete version, which I put into @marmot's answer above (except for the color coding):

```
% ---DOCUMENT CLASS---
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

% ---MISC. PACKAGES---
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% ---TIKZ---
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

% ---PLOTS---
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{1.csv}
0, 0
0.020000, -0.000347
0.040000, -0.009989
0.060000, -0.033917
0.080000, -0.066399
0.100000, -0.102985
0.120000, -0.140917
0.140000, -0.178608
0.160000, -0.215232
0.180000, -0.250425
0.200000, -0.284078
0.220000, -0.316210
0.240000, -0.346897
0.260000, -0.376240
0.280000, -0.404339
0.300000, -0.431294
0.320000, -0.457194
0.340000, -0.482119
0.780000, -0.873711
0.800000, -0.886640
0.820000, -0.899258
0.840000, -0.911571
0.860000, -0.923589
0.880000, -0.935319
0.900000, -0.946767
0.920000, -0.957940
0.940000, -0.968844
0.960000, -0.979485
0.980000, -0.989869
1.000000, -1.000000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{2.csv}
0, 0
0.002644, -0.020000
0.006417, -0.040000
0.011080, -0.060000
0.016513, -0.080000
0.022645, -0.100000
0.029425, -0.120000
0.036820, -0.140000
0.044804, -0.160000
0.053358, -0.180000
0.062468, -0.200000
0.072123, -0.220000
0.082316, -0.240000
0.093042, -0.260000
0.104298, -0.280000
0.116083, -0.300000
0.128398, -0.320000
0.141246, -0.340000
0.154629, -0.360000
0.168553, -0.380000
0.183024, -0.400000
0.198051, -0.420000
0.213643, -0.440000
0.229810, -0.460000
0.246564, -0.480000
0.263919, -0.500000
0.281891, -0.520000
0.300496, -0.540000
0.643284, -0.820000
0.675487, -0.840000
0.709127, -0.860000
0.744333, -0.880000
0.781261, -0.900000
0.820097, -0.920000
0.861068, -0.940000
0.904455, -0.960000
0.950612, -0.980000
1.000000, -1.000000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{3.csv}
0, 0
0.007957, -0.055479
0.010327, -0.065792
0.013265, -0.077471
0.016876, -0.090623
0.021278, -0.105355
0.026607, -0.121775
0.033015, -0.139989
0.040673, -0.160100
0.049771, -0.182208
0.060520, -0.206407
0.073158, -0.232783
0.087945, -0.261415
0.105170, -0.292368
0.125154, -0.325696
0.148248, -0.361432
0.174844, -0.399593
0.205373, -0.440170
0.280191, -0.528391
0.325606, -0.575855
0.377226, -0.625362
0.435812, -0.676699
0.502248, -0.729587
0.577578, -0.783662
0.663074, -0.838455
0.760352, -0.893359
0.871594, -0.947572
1.000000, -1.000000
\end{filecontents*}


\def\reverseyaxis#1{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1*-1}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \datavisualization [school book axes,
                            all axes={length=6cm},
                            x axis={min value=0,max value=1,ticks={step=0.5,minor steps between steps=4}},
                            y axis={min value=-1,max value=1,ticks={step=0.5,minor steps between steps=4,tick typesetter/.code=\reverseyaxis{##1}}},
                            yscale=-1,
                            visualize as scatter]%

            data[headline={x, y}, read from file={1.csv}]
            data[headline={x, y}, read from file={2.csv}]
            data[headline={x, y}, read from file={3.csv}]
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: datavisualization with flipped y-axis]

You'll notice that the axis arrow is now pointing down.  The axes visualizations are customizable, but I do not know exactly what you need...so I left it this way for now.

**Second approach: (image is the same as approach #1)**

I found a slightly different way that doesn't require a new command and re-calculating the y-axis ticks.  It's not automatic, however, and requires using the same length from `all axes={length=6cm}` (in my example).  You need these three options in `\datavisualization`:

- `all axes={length=6cm}`
- `yscale=-1`
- `y axis={min value=-1,max value=1,ticks={step=0.5,minor steps between
  steps=4,rotate=180,yshift=-6cm}}`

Same code as above, but here is the `tikzpicture` code for version #2:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \datavisualization [school book axes,
                            all axes={length=6cm},
                            x axis={min value=0,max value=1,ticks={step=0.5,minor steps between steps=4}},
                            yscale=-1,
                            y axis={min value=-1,max value=1,ticks={step=0.5,minor steps between steps=4,rotate=180,yshift=-6cm}},
                            visualize as scatter]%

            data[headline={x, y}, read from file={1.csv}]
            data[headline={x, y}, read from file={2.csv}]
            data[headline={x, y}, read from file={3.csv}]
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The approach takes advantage of simply rotating the y-axis 180 degrees.  The problem is that the pivot point is not as 0, but at the maximum value on the y-axis.  Therefore, you need to shift it downwards by the length of the y-axis.

Comment: @marmot I tried using `before survey` and `after visualization`, but it required putting together a data group.  I was seeing if I could avoid doing that with this approach.  I ended up stumbling upon the second approach which uses `yshift` after I realized you could 'cheat' with the axis rotation.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for updating your question!

I do not have much experience with data visualization. The only thing I can offer is a pgfplots version of your graph. There sign flip can be achieved simply by adding the key `y dir=reverse`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{1.csv}
0, 0
0.020000, -0.000347
0.040000, -0.009989
0.060000, -0.033917
0.080000, -0.066399
0.100000, -0.102985
0.120000, -0.140917
0.140000, -0.178608
0.160000, -0.215232
0.180000, -0.250425
0.200000, -0.284078
0.220000, -0.316210
0.240000, -0.346897
0.260000, -0.376240
0.280000, -0.404339
0.300000, -0.431294
0.320000, -0.457194
0.340000, -0.482119
0.780000, -0.873711
0.800000, -0.886640
0.820000, -0.899258
0.840000, -0.911571
0.860000, -0.923589
0.880000, -0.935319
0.900000, -0.946767
0.920000, -0.957940
0.940000, -0.968844
0.960000, -0.979485
0.980000, -0.989869
1.000000, -1.000000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{2.csv}
0, 0
0.002644, -0.020000
0.006417, -0.040000
0.011080, -0.060000
0.016513, -0.080000
0.022645, -0.100000
0.029425, -0.120000
0.036820, -0.140000
0.044804, -0.160000
0.053358, -0.180000
0.062468, -0.200000
0.072123, -0.220000
0.082316, -0.240000
0.093042, -0.260000
0.104298, -0.280000
0.116083, -0.300000
0.128398, -0.320000
0.141246, -0.340000
0.154629, -0.360000
0.168553, -0.380000
0.183024, -0.400000
0.198051, -0.420000
0.213643, -0.440000
0.229810, -0.460000
0.246564, -0.480000
0.263919, -0.500000
0.281891, -0.520000
0.300496, -0.540000
0.643284, -0.820000
0.675487, -0.840000
0.709127, -0.860000
0.744333, -0.880000
0.781261, -0.900000
0.820097, -0.920000
0.861068, -0.940000
0.904455, -0.960000
0.950612, -0.980000
1.000000, -1.000000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{3.csv}
0, 0
0.007957, -0.055479
0.010327, -0.065792
0.013265, -0.077471
0.016876, -0.090623
0.021278, -0.105355
0.026607, -0.121775
0.033015, -0.139989
0.040673, -0.160100
0.049771, -0.182208
0.060520, -0.206407
0.073158, -0.232783
0.087945, -0.261415
0.105170, -0.292368
0.125154, -0.325696
0.148248, -0.361432
0.174844, -0.399593
0.205373, -0.440170
0.280191, -0.528391
0.325606, -0.575855
0.377226, -0.625362
0.435812, -0.676699
0.502248, -0.729587
0.577578, -0.783662
0.663074, -0.838455
0.760352, -0.893359
0.871594, -0.947572
1.000000, -1.000000
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,y dir=reverse,
    y axis line style={stealth-},xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,enlargelimits=0.1]
    \addplot+[only marks] table[header=false,x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma] {1.csv};
    \addplot+[only marks] table[header=false,x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma] {2.csv};
    \addplot+[only marks] table[header=false,x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma] {3.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've added the filecontents above---I've extended with their tails to show what the complete graph looks like more or less. Thanks for your time. By the way, somehow one of the three graphs isn't even displaying now.

Comment: @Anakhand Before I had three times the same data, so points just got overwritten. I am sorry not to be able to provide you an elegant `data visualization` answer, but only a possible way to use `pgfplots` for that.